# plus symbol changes to space when sending data to a php acript and saving in mysql table through android

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, httpurlconnection

I am trying to send an arraylist converted to string and then urlencoded to a php script through a POST requestwhich will save that data in a mysql table. Everything is fine except the '+' symbol in the database are replaced by ' '(space).

This is the javacode in android that i am using to send POST request

`ContactNumbers` is an ArrayList containg phonemunbers

`ContactNumbers.toString()` is  `[+919401557473, +919085425753, +919435448667, +9954263031]`

```
            param = "param="+ContactNumbers.toString(),;

            try {
                String yourURL = "http://54.169.88.65/events/eventmain/get_users2.php";
                URL url = new URL(yourURL);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                connection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(param.getBytes().length);
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8"));
                writer.write(param);
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                out.close();
                connection.connect();
```

The `php` script `get_users2.php` that i am using is as follows:

```
<?php

$r = $_POST['param'];
mysql_connect("localhost","root","magento");
mysql_select_db("Eventmain");
$sql = "INSERT INTO `data`(`data`) VALUES ('$r')";
mysql_query($sql);

?>
```

The `data` table in mysql is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `data` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `data` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

The column `data` has `Collation` equal to `utf8_general_ci`.

Please Help.

Comment: Juz take a look at your php code... Replace VALUES ('$r')"; with VALUES (`$r`)";   Juz check the difference in the quotes of $r.

Comment: @Rishad Appat Nothing gets inserted in the database if i do that. may be sql exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact is that you are URLEncoding params on Android side, and then URLDecoding them with your PHP script.

Unfortunately, the URL decoding of a '+' is a whitespace.

You can try to change your '+' character on your Android application with another character that is not affected by URL Encoding/Decoding, and then on PHP side you can substitute that character with '+' after URL decoding.

Comment: I have edited my code ,please check it out again, I have removed the encoding part from both client and server side but still the '+' symbols are becoming ' '(space) in mysql table. Please reply.

Comment: You should debug. Print out the params before the sending, and then print out them after you take them from the $POST variable. Is '+' already missing? Because, to me, this seems like an URL encoding/decoding issue.
Another thing you can look at is if those "params" are put in the URL itself (in a GET fashion), or if they are really in the POST body. If they're in the URL, chances are that they will be encoded/decoded anyway, regardless of the "manual" methods you just removed.

Comment: I'd make a substitution on the Android side, changing the '+' in every parameter with another character you know that's not used, let's say '.' (dot). Then, on PHP side, I'll substitute them back to '+'.

Comment: Thanks man, i replaced the characters as you said it works fine. But still i can't figure out the issue.

Comment: I'm not an expert on Android and PHP side, so I cannot say. It could be due to the fact that params were passed through the URL for some reason, thus they got decoded on PHP side. But I'm not sure about it.